# How to get Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 working?

Tags: wireless, drivers, intel-wireless

Initially wireless did not work - it would find wireless and would start connecting, but it would just keep prompting for the password and never connected.

I found [this proposed fix on LinuxMint.com](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/608) which installs an older version of the microcode (firmware) for my device.

That seems to have disabled any wireless capability. `rfkill list all` shows nothing and there is no wireless option in my 'taskbar'.

I'm a Linux newbie so bear with me, and let me know if I can add any command outputs that might help you help me resolve this issue! :)

`sudo lspci -nn`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller [8086:0104] (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port [8086:0101] (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1c10] (rev b4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:1c14] (rev b4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:1c16] (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1c26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller [8086:1c4b] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller [8086:1c03] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1c22] (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF106 [GeForce GTX 460M] [10de:0dd1] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GF106 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0be9] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [8086:0083]
04:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1033:0194] (rev 03)
```

[`/var/log/udev` output](http://pastebin.com/KwYmgAMT).

[`/var/log/dmesg` output](http://pastebin.com/Ts5Aftrz).

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Updated! http://pastebin.com/Ts5Aftrz for /var/log/dmesg

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you try this:

```
sudo su
mv /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode.backup /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 bt_coex_active=N" > /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
exit
```

Reboot and tell us if your wireless is working as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This restored wireless capability but the problem persists the same as before. I'm going to have a look at the link in the other comment and get some hardware details for you guys in a sec.

Comment: I just can't sift through 14k+ lines to try to decipher what's wrong. How about a pastebin of: cat /var/log/syslog | grep etwork | tail -n30 taken just after you tried and failed to connect. dmesg doesn't show anything wrong for iwlwifi or its dependencies which is why I'd like to turn to Network Manager. Is your router set to WPA and WPA2 mixed mode? Many drivers prefer WPA2 only and not mixed mode.

Comment: I'm sorry! I have no idea how those logs are read anyway. http://pastebin.com/AtzXHWHM here you go