# Internet keeps disconnecting from AP & network-manager needs to be restarted every few minutes

Tags: 12.04, wireless, internet, network-manager

This happens with two different-vendor access points.

Internet disconnects while the `nm-applet` is showing connected.

Although, `nm-applet` shows that am connected and I got IP address but I even can't ping the router/my default gateway!!

So, I need to keep restarting the "`/etc/init.d/network-manager`" in order to work again just for a few minutes.

PS: The AP are working properly with my iPad, my Nexus 4 mobile and even with my brother's windows machine.

Relevant `lspci` output:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [8086:0084]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 BGN [8086:1315]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Kernel version: `3.2.0-37-generic`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please include *specific* information in your question. To be able to answer your question, we'll need at least the following. What is the exact hardware in your PC? (post output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(network|wireless|ethernet)"`) What do the logs of Network Manager tell you the time your connection is poor/interrupted? (inspect `/var/log/syslog` - if nothing, that's also valuable.) What kernel are you on and did you apply all system updates? (post output of `uname -r`)

Comment: Please **edit** your question to provide more information. It's how this site works - it's not a discussion forum. And does [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/235673/88802) help you out?