# Wifi not working on Lenovo z570 Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, lenovo

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 Precise on a Lenovo Z570, but the WiFi isn't working. I noticed that the WiFi Network is `UNCLAIMED` using the command `sudo lshw -C network`. Anybody can help?

WiFi card: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000

Here are my system info:

```
salim@ss-host:~$ uname -a
Linux ss-host 3.5.0-37-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 8 22:10:28 UTC 2013 i686 i686  i386 GNU/Linux
```

`dmesg | grep iwl` returns nothing.

```
salim@ss-host:~$ sudo lshw -C network

  -network UNCLAIMED   
   description: Network controller
   product: Centrino Wireless-N 1000
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f1500000-f1501fff
   -network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 05
   serial: f0:de:f1
```

```
salim@ss-host:~$ ifconfig

    eth0  
       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:de:f1:f5:35:45 
              inet addr:93.185.234.79  Bcast:93.185.235.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::f2de:f1ff:fef5:3545/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:237882 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:151943 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:250091722 (250.0 MB)  TX bytes:11595953 (11.5 MB)

    lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
              inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
              inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
              UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
              RX packets:1032 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:1032 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:115095 (115.0 KB)  TX bytes:115095 (115.0 KB)
```

```
salim@ss-host:~$ lspci |grep Network
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000
```

Thank you.

Comment: try this [How to get Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 working?](http://askubuntu.com/q/235644) .. in your previous version of this question, you said you copied compiled iw module .. please include that information also if so.

Comment: Hi Alaa, I tried the to copy the compiled driver to /lib/firmware but it didn't works, I deprecated such information since I found it not useful, and could mislead the user. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Wifi issue has been fixed, once I have updated my Ubuntu machine, and the Wifi/blue-tooth are detected, etc. Also, the Wifi hardware it's not anymore flagged as UNCLAIMED, it's recognized now using the (lshw -C Network).

Best,